How do I get .resample().interpolate() to not ignore data points that don't fit the rule?
I have a time series on an irregular time grid. I would like to interpolate this data linearly to a regular time grid. As an simplified example, please look onto the following code:
import pandas as pd

data = {'2020-01-01': 0.0,
        '2020-01-02': 5.0,
        '2020-01-05': 2.0}
series = pd.Series({pd.to_datetime(x): y for x, y in data.items()})
series_interp = series.resample('2D').interpolate()

print(series_interp)

If I do this interpolation by hand, I would expect the following result:
# 2020-01-01    0.0
# 2020-01-03    4.0
# 2020-01-05    2.0
# Freq: 2D, dtype: float64

However, the code above gives:
# 2020-01-01    0.0
# 2020-01-03    1.0
# 2020-01-05    2.0
# Freq: 2D, dtype: float64

Obviously, the value on 2020-01-03 has been calculated by interpolating between the values of 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-05. The measurement on 2020-01-02 has been ignored. Is it possible to achieve the expected result using pd.Series.resample()?
A working way to perform the interpolation is:
index_new = pd.date_range(series.index.min(), series.index.max(), freq='2D')
series_interp = series.reindex(series.index.union(index_new))
series_interp.interpolate('index', inplace=True)
series_interp = series_interp.reindex(index_new)
print(series_interp)

This yields the correct result. However, it is somewhat cumbersome. Is it possible to get the same result using the convenience method resample of the time series?

That title is really vague. If I could suggest a better one: "How do I get .resample().interpolate() to not ignore data points that don't fit the rule?" For tips on writing a good title, check out [ask]. Please [edit] to improve it.

The intermediates are as following:
# first it reindexes:
series.resample('2D').first()

2020-01-01    0.0
2020-01-03    NaN
2020-01-05    2.0
Freq: 2D, dtype: float64

# then it interpolates:
series.resample('2D').first().interpolate()

2020-01-01    0.0
2020-01-03    1.0
2020-01-05    2.0
Freq: 2D, dtype: float64

You could resample.interpolate on the minimal unit (1D) then keep only every other day:
series.resample('1D').interpolate()[::2]

2020-01-01    0.0
2020-01-03    4.0
2020-01-05    2.0
Freq: 2D, dtype: float64

Intermediate:
series.resample('1D').interpolate()

2020-01-01    0.0
2020-01-02    5.0
2020-01-03    4.0
2020-01-04    3.0
2020-01-05    2.0
Freq: D, dtype: float64

Variant if the target frequency is not a multiple of the unit:
# minimal common frequency is 0.5D
series.resample('0.5D').interpolate().resample('1.5D').first()
# or
series.resample('0.5D').interpolate()[::3]

2020-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2020-01-02 12:00:00    4.5
2020-01-04 00:00:00    3.0
Freq: 36h, dtype: float64


This is an interesting approach. However, it will not apply very well to my original use case, where the minimal time difference between the samples might be very small and the total time span is large. In that case, I would have to resample first to the smallest step between the samples which may result in problems with the available memory.
However, I do understand better now, what .resample really does and I think it is not very well applicable for my problem.
